# How can I create multiple lists with intersection from one original list?

Tags: python, list

For example, if I had the list:

```
list_a = [5, 2, 30, 6, 17]
```

The lists I want to obtain relate to the len(list_b), for example:

```
list_b = [40, 90]
```

So the lists I need to create are:

```
[5, 2]
[2, 30]
[30, 6]
[6, 17]
```

How can I slice or use a loop to do this?

Comment: what if the len(list_b) == 3? what is the intersection len of two adjacent lists in the result?

Comment: @DeepSpace list_a=[1,2,3,4,5] len(list_b) == 3, result==[1,2,3],[3,4,5] or [1,2,3],[2,3,4],[3,4,5]?

Comment: @Keloo the result should ==[1,2,3],[2,3,4],[3,4,5]

Comment: @crtbk I voted for a reopen but until this happens, you can work with `res = [list_a[i:i+size] for i in range(len(list_a)-size+1)]` assuming `size = len(list_b)`

Answer (score 0):

Here is one solution using `itertools.islice`. This reduces the need to build lists which might otherwise be used to feed a `zip` function.

```
from itertools import islice

a = [5, 2, 30, 6, 17]
b = [40, 90, 20]

n = len(b)

slices = (islice(a, i, None) for i in range(1, n))
res = list(zip(*(a, *slices)))

# [(5, 2, 30), (2, 30, 6), (30, 6, 17)]
```